# F# web server library

Tags: http, f#

Is there a web server library for F#, similar to SimpleHTTPServer in Python?

Installing a full server like IIS is overkill for what I want, which is a simple application that can be queried using a web browser, effectively using HTTP as a monitoring method. Ideally, a request to the address `/engines/id/state` would map to a function `get_state(engine_id)` which I provide.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A self-hosted WCF service is not a bad start; here's a tiny one for starters:

```
open System
open System.IO 
// add reference to these two guys, need .NET full (not client profile)
open System.ServiceModel
open System.ServiceModel.Web

[<ServiceContract>]
type MyContract() =
    [<OperationContract>]
    [<WebGet(UriTemplate="{s}/{t}")>]
    member this.Get(s:string, t:string) : Stream =
        let html = sprintf @"
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"">
<html><head></head><body>Called with '%s' and '%s'</body></html>" s t
        upcast new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html))

let Main() =
    let address = "http://localhost:64385/"
    let host = new WebServiceHost(typeof<MyContract>, new Uri(address))
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof<MyContract>, new WebHttpBinding(), "") 
        |> ignore
    host.Open()
    printfn "Server running at %s" address
    printfn "Press a key to close server"
    System.Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
    host.Close()

Main()
// now go hit 
// http://localhost:64385/foo/42
// in your browser
```

Comment: After executing I get `Exception DispatchOperation '*' for contract 'MyContract' requires Invoker.   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationInvokerHandler.EnsureValid (System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperation operation) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0` on the server and text starting with "falsetrue1310.." on the browser. I am using F# with Mono on OS X so may be there is a bug there. Any hint on what to look for?

Comment: you should probably add a "Mono" tag to your question

Comment: No problem. I just used mono as the test machine that I have access to at the moment. I need it in a Windows application tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks. The application works in Windows with a small snag, the text is downloaded rather than opened as a web page. My guess is that it needs a header `text/html` sent somehow.

Comment: You can change the content type by adding this to the `Get` method: `         WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType <- "text/html"` (There might be an easier way / a global setting.)

Answer (score 4):

I have not looked into this at all, but maybe glance at

https://github.com/SuaveIO/suave/blob/master/README.md

> Suave is a simple web development F#
>   library providing a lightweight web
>   server and a set of combinators to
>   manipulate route flow and task
>   composition.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [frack](http://github.com/panesofglass/frack) (a Rack-like interface), and if you need a nicer syntax, [frank](http://github.com/panesofglass/frank) (which builds on top of frack).

There's also [Kayak](http://kayakhttp.com/), it's written on C# but you could easily use it from F#.

Comment: I think the correct link to Kayak is now https://github.com/kayak/kayak/ at least if you care about the source code.